# JSON not properly inserting into mysql through php

Tags: php, mysql, json, sql-insert

I have been trying to insert data from a json file into mysql through php.
I have a function doing the insert in one file, while the decoding is done in another file.
When I run the code, I recieve this error:

```
You could not be registered due to a system error. We apologize for any inconvenience.

Column 'password' cannot be null

Query: INSERT INTO users (id, email, password, username, deviceId, date_created) VALUES (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW() )
Query was executed

enter code here
```

Here are my three files:

insertion.php:

```
//Require files
require('functions.php');
if(file_exists('data.json')){
    echo "The file exists ";

    $file= file_get_contents('data.json');
    echo json_encode('data.json');

    $data=json_decode($file, true);

    var_dump($data);

$email= $data["email"];
$password= $data["password"];
$username= $data["username"];
$deviceId= $data["deviceId"];
$tableName= 'users';
$email= "email@example.com";

$error=json_last_error();
echo "<br><br>";
echo "your email shoudl be displayed right here: ".$email. "This is email";
echo "<br>JSON Errors will display here:". $error;

$execute= dataInsert($tableName, $email, $password, $username, $deviceId);

if($execute){
    echo "Query was executed";


}



}
else{

echo "file does not exist";

}
```

functions.php:

```
//------------------------dataInsert()---------------------------//

function dataInsert($tableName, $email, $password, $username, $deviceId){


//set database connection
require('mysqli_connect.php');
 if($dbc){
  echo "<h3>connection successful</h3>";

 }

//form query using the values and tablename
$query = "INSERT INTO users (id, email, password, username, deviceId, date_created) 
VALUES (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW() )"; 


//Prepare statement
$stmt= mysqli_prepare($dbc, $query);


//Bind the variables

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sssi', $email, $password, $username, $deviceId);


//Execute the query

$result=mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);



if($result){
    echo "Success !";

}
else{
    // Public message:
        echo 'System Error
        <p class="error">You could not be registered due to a system error. We apologize for any inconvenience.</p>'; 

        // Debugging message:
        echo '<p>' . mysqli_error($dbc) . '<br /><br />Query: ' . $query . '</p>';

}

mysqli_close($dbc); // Close the database connection.
return true;
}
```

data.json

```
<pre>
<code>
{"users":[
{
    "email":"fakeemail@gmail.net",
    "password":"mypass12",
    "username":"myusername",
    "deviceId":"21"
 }

]}
```

When I use var_dump to display the json array, it looks correct:

```
"data.json"array(1) { ["users"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(4) { ["email"]=> string(19) "fakeemail@gmail.net" ["password"]=> string(6) "mypass12" ["username"]=> string(13) "myusername" ["deviceId"]=> string(2) "21" } } }
```

I've been able to insert rows into the database, but they were all blank, besides the date, and auto increment id. When I set $email= email@example.com it will display the password cannot be null, but commenting that line out will cause the error to display 'email' cannot be null

Comment: try removing id in your query insert

Comment: I removed id in the insert and null from the values, but I still get the same error

Comment: also try to remove the query param date_created

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting null into your ID field. Try removing that.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the values of the decoded json string wrongly, passing true as the second value of json_decode you get one associative array.

```
var_dump($data['users'][0]['email']);
```

Result

```
fakeemail@...
```

So you could do something like

```
if (count($data['users'])) 
{
    foreach($data['users'] as $user) 
    {
        // insert query passing
        // $user['email'], $user['password'],
        print $user['email'];
    }
}
```